# how to integrate php id in timeline javascript code

Tags: php, jquery, html, timeline

i have on page.php a code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var timeline_data = [{
            content:' <div class="classdiv"> <div id="proID" >$rows[$id]</div> </div> '; ?>, 
        }];
        $().product('.classdiv');
    });
</script>
```

When the timeline loading div, 
the div `<div class="classdiv"> <div id="proID" >$rows[$id]</div> </div>` have correct ID.

HTML is generated correctly

```
<div class = "classdiv"> <div id = "proID"> 123 </ div> </ div>,
<div class = "classdiv"> <div id = "proID"> 243 </ div> </ div>,
<div class = "classdiv"> <div id = "proID"> 423 </ div> </ div>,
<div class = "classdiv"> <div id = "proID"> 743 </ div> </ div>,
```

But page.php, displays in all div content only for a single ID

```
<div class = "classdiv"> <div id = "proID"> 123 </ div> </ div>,
<div class = "classdiv"> <div id = "proID"> 123 </ div> </ div>,
<div class = "classdiv"> <div id = "proID"> 123 </ div> </ div>,
<div class = "classdiv"> <div id = "proID"> 123 </ div> </ div>,
```

Please tell me what is the solution?

Comment: This code looks incomplete. It's hard to understand your problem. One obvious issue is that element `id` must be unique. So having multiple `prodID` divs on the page will cause problems.

Comment: Provide the code for when you are looping `$rows` and what you do with `timeline_data`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, This `timeline_data` , generating more posts, and each post contains this div `<div class="classdiv"> <div id="proID" >$rows[$id]</div> </div>`

Comment: The problem is: in this moment the timeline_data on background generate code correctly
`<div class = "classdiv"> <div id = "proID"> 123 </ div> </ div>,
<div class = "classdiv"> <div id = "proID"> 243 </ div> </ div>,
<div class = "classdiv"> <div id = "proID"> 423 </ div> </ div>,
<div class = "classdiv"> <div id = "proID"> 743 </ div> </ div>,`

Comment: , but displayed this timeline_data, posts only with id =123
`<div class = "classdiv"> <div id = "proID"> 123 </ div> </ div>,
<div class = "classdiv"> <div id = "proID"> 123 </ div> </ div>,
<div class = "classdiv"> <div id = "proID"> 123 </ div> </ div>,
<div class = "classdiv"> <div id = "proID"> 123 </ div> </ div>,`

Comment: Please show PHP loop and how you append timeline_data.

Comment: I suppose you're right, because conflict makes divs